# Failed to launch geckodriver with FireFox browser - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, automation, geckodriver

System req.

1. Eclipse version- 2020-03 (4.15.0)
2. TestNG version 7.0.1
3. Selenium-java pom dependancy - 3.14.0
4. FireFox browser version- 77.0.1 (64-bit)
5. geckodriver.exe -0.26.0

   ```
       System.out.println("geckodriver");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\MyEclipseWorkspace\\mavenProject\\browsers\\geckodriver.exe");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       System.out.println("geckodriver launched.");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
       Thread.sleep(2000);
   ```

following error is displayed.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
geckodriver
FAILED: geckdriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.locateFirefoxBinariesFromPlatform(FirefoxBinary.java:403)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at mavenProject.geckdrivr.geckdriver(geckdrivr.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is my code(Pay attention to your webdrive path)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\MyEclipseWorkspace\\mavenProject\\browsers\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

If not, please attach the error code